# javascript global variable undefined in jquery get

Tags: javascript

How to assign value to global variable

```
function ok(){ 
    var idglobal; 

    $.get("<?php echo base_url('testchat/rtc/showchat'); ?>", function (data) {
        data = $.parseJSON(data);

        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            idglobal = item.id;
        });
    });
}

console.log(idglobal);
```

> above this code to assign value to global variable but the result is undefined

Answer (score 0):

You console.log isn't printing it because it runs before the promise resolves.

Try:

```
  function ok(){ 
   var idglobal; 
            $.get("<?php echo base_url('testchat/rtc/showchat'); ?>", function (data) {
                data = $.parseJSON(data);
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    idglobal = item.id;
                });
                console.log(idglobal);
            });
            }
```

The value of idglobal should be the last `item.id`.

Comment: And to be clear the value of `idglobal` will only ever be the last id of the returned data.

Comment: yes its work, but how to print value after $.get ?

Comment: Glad it answers your question. Regarding your second question: console.log will run after $.get finishes. Your callback is executed once the HTTP request finishes.